# SQL query to pivot a column using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, pivot

I have the following table:

```
Bank:
name  val   amount
John   1     2000
Peter  1     1999
Peter  2     1854
John   2     1888
```

I am trying to write an SQL query to give the following result:

```
name  amountVal1 amountVal2  
John    2000        1888   
Peter   1999        1854
```

So far I have this:

```
SELECT name,
CASE WHEN val = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS amountVal1,
CASE WHEN val = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS amountVal2
FROM bank
```

However, it gives the slightly wrong result:

```
name  amountVal1 amountVal2  
John    2000        0
Peter   1999        0
John    0          1888   
Peter   0          1854
```

How can I modify my query to give the correct presentation?
 Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN val = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS amountVal1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN val = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS amountVal2
FROM bank GROUP BY name
```

Comment: That did the trick. I tried using Group by without the SUM and it didn't work. I see now that you could have the same name, with many different values under the columns amountVal1/2. Therefore I assume the `group by name` wouldn't know what to do with the numbers. In this case, we need to tell it to SUM them! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to join the table on itself. Try this:

```
select bank1.name, bank1.amount, bank2.amount
from bank bank1
inner join bank bank2 on 
    bank1.name = bank2.name 
    and bank1.val = 1 
    and bank2.val = 2
```

Comment: Thanks I think this would work also, but I don't want to create a temporary table if possible.

Comment: @Roger: This will not create any temporary table. In some cases, it may even be faster than the `GROUP BY - CASE` approach.

Comment: But this will show different results if there are persons with rows only for `val=1` or `val=2`. Or with more than one row with same value.