# how to merge a query result by datetime in same table mysql?

Tags: mysql, datetime, merge

All,

I need your help to merge the result in the same datetime in mysql.

I do **a query of two tables** like :

```
SELECT b.ID, b.DateTime, b.Value 
FROM tableA a, tableB b 
WHERE (a.Id=1) OR (a.Id=2) OR (a.Id=3) AND (a.Id = b.ID) 
      AND (b.DateTime Between '2011-04-02 06:00' And '2011-04-02 06:05')
```

**Query result :**

```
| ID  |    DateTime      | Value |
----------------------------------
| 1   | 2011-04-02 06:00 | 20    | 
| 1   | 2011-04-02 06:05 | 21    | 
| 2   | 2011-04-02 06:00 | 10    | 
| 2   | 2011-04-02 06:05 | 16    | 
| 3   | 2011-04-02 06:00 | 23    | 
| 3   | 2011-04-02 06:05 | 22    |
```

All i want is to make **a result** like :

```
|    DateTime      | ID_1    | ID_2   | ID_3   | 
------------------------------------------------
| 2011-04-02 06:00 |  20     |   10   | 23     | 
| 2011-04-02 06:05 |  21     |   16   | 22     |
```

I hope there is a solution for this.

Thank you before for all your help.

Regards, 
YougyZ

Comment: This is called a pivot table and there are many answers to this problem on SO, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846007/sql-query-to-pivot-a-column-using-case-when

Comment: Thanks, the difficulty is when i use the datetime, but i will try it.. I will let you know after it..

Comment: Thanks @liquorvicar for the solution...

I have tried this query :

    `SELECT b.Date, SUM(CASE WHEN a.Id=1 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Mac1, SUM(CASE WHEN a.Id=2 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Mac2, SUM(CASE WHEN a.Id=3 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Mac3 FROM TableA a, TableB b WHERE (a.Id = b.ID) AND (b.Date Between '2011-04-02 06:00' And '2011-04-02 06:05') GROUP BY b.DA_Date`

The Result is just like what i need.. :)

Comment: You can post this as an answer to your question and accept it. Then others won't waste time reading your question, since it's solved anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I want but i cant, because i have not enough points to do it, or i must wait until 8 hours after i post my question.. And Then, i can answer my question. Thanks btw..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @liquorvicar for the solution...

I have tried this query :

```
SELECT b.Date, 
SUM(CASE WHEN a.Id=1 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Mac1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN a.Id=2 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Mac2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN a.Id=3 THEN b.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Mac3 
FROM TableA a, TableB b 
WHERE (a.Id = b.ID) AND (b.Date Between '2011-04-02 06:00' And '2011-04-02 06:05') 
GROUP BY b.DA_Date
```

The Result is just like what i need.. :)