# take rows as columns in pivot table in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this sql select statement:

```
Select ORDERS.ptDate as Date,Products.Description as Product, 
            ORDERDETAILS2.Quantity   FROM         ORDERS inner join ORDERDetails2 on Orders._id=ORDERDetails2.PtOrder inner join Products on Orderdetails2.ptproduct=Products.PtUnique order by date
```

which retutrns this kind of data:

```
2014-03-19 00:00:00;"Product a";"4"
2014-03-19 00:00:00;"Product c";"750"
2014-03-19 00:00:00;"Product a";"1"
2014-03-19 00:00:00;"Product b";"1"
2014-03-19 00:00:00;"Product c";"1075"
2014-03-20 00:00:00;"Product b";"2"
2014-03-20 00:00:00;"Product b";"1"
2014-03-20 00:00:00;"Product a";"2"
2014-03-20 00:00:00;"Product c";"2"
2014-03-20 00:00:00;"Product b";"25"
```

can I reproduce this having dates as columns , second column as rows  and third column as aggegate function in sqlite?
The result should be this:

```
Product      2014-03-19    2014-03-20
Product a        5              2
Product b        1              28
Product c      1825             2
```

Thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to pivot a column using CASE WHEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846007/sql-query-to-pivot-a-column-using-case-when)

Comment: I don't know from start how many dates will be at table. So i can't use select case(I think)

Comment: If you do not know the number of dates you will have to make a dynamic query. SQLite does not have a built-in support for dynamic queries, so you will have to do this on an application level (i.e. in the code)

Comment: Any example of this dynamic query?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a dynamic query, i.e., you have to generate the SQL code for each date.

First, get the dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ptDate
FROM Orders
ORDER BY ptDate
```

Then, begin with a query that returns *one* record for each desired product:

```
SELECT Description AS Product
FROM Products
```

(If you want to restrict this to products in some specific orders, you have to do joins here, or use `WHERE PtUnique IN (...)`.)

Then write a query that combines these products with one column for each date.
These values must be computed with correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT Description AS Product,
       (SELECT SUM(OrderDetails2.Quantity)
        FROM OrderDetails2
        JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails2.PtOrder = Orders._id
        WHERE Orders.ptDate = '2014-03-19'
          AND OrderDetails2.PtProduct = Products.PtUnique
       ) AS "2014-03-19",
       (SELECT SUM(OrderDetails2.Quantity)
        FROM OrderDetails2
        JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails2.PtOrder = Orders._id
        WHERE Orders.ptDate = '2014-03-20'
          AND OrderDetails2.PtProduct = Products.PtUnique
       ) AS "2014-03-20"
FROM Products
```

Comment: In code i created a sqldatareader taking dates as you advised, and after i created a string this way:
    While sqReader.Read()
                    codIds = codIds & "," & "Sum(case when date=" & "'" & sqReader.GetString(sqReader.GetOrdinal("ptdate")) & "'" & " then (quantity)end)  as " & "'" & sqReader.GetString(sqReader.GetOrdinal("ptdate")).Substring(0, 10) & "'"
                End While

after i combined this string with this way:
    pSql = "Select  Product "
                pSql = pSql & codIds
                pSql = pSql & " FROM Tameio1 group by Product"
so it worked.